# Updating the same table that is being queried

Tags: mysql, sql

This query works as expected and returns the missing customers numbers.

```
SELECT *
FROM Person_Details AS b
     INNER JOIN Person_Details AS a ON a.holdername = b.holdername
                                       AND a.District = b.District
                                       AND a.Dob = b.DOb
                                       AND a.Address = b.Address
WHERE b.customer_No IS NULL limit 10
```

What I need to do is to find the customer numbers for given "holdernames" and update where-ever it is NULL. I expect the following update to work. But it updates 0 records.

```
update Person_Details as b inner join Person_Details as a
on a.holdername = b.holdername  and a.District = b.District   and a.Dob = b.DOb and a.Address = b.Address 
set b.customer_no = a.customer_No 
where b.customer_No is null
```

Am I using the update with self join correctly?

---

---

update:

When I tried it with test case, it is working as expected. But when I use the same query on production server, it does not update any rows. I just wanted to know if I am missing somethig obvious.

```
create table Person_Details (holdername varchar(100), District varchar(100),
                             Dob varchar(100), Address varchar(100), customer_No int);

                             insert into Person_Details values ('shantanu', 'mumbai', '1970-11-16', 'india', 123);
                             insert into Person_Details values ('shantanu', 'mumbai', '1970-11-16', 'india', NULL);
                             insert into Person_Details values ('akbar', 'delhi', '1995-12-11', 'india', 987);


select * from  Person_Details as b inner join Person_Details as a
on a.holdername = b.holdername  and a.District = b.District  and a.Dob = b.DOb and a.Address = b.Address 
where b.customer_No is null
limit 10;

update Person_Details as b inner join Person_Details as a
on a.holdername = b.holdername  and a.District = b.District   and a.Dob = b.DOb and a.Address = b.Address 
set b.customer_no = a.customer_No 
where b.customer_No is null
```

Comment: Show your sample data set and make sure its null not empty '' both are different

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

**and a.customer_no IS NOT NULL** so....

```
update Person_Details as b inner 
join Person_Details as a 
on a.holdername = b.holdername  
and a.District = b.District
and a.Dob = b.DOb 
and a.Address = b.Address 
and a.customer_no IS NOT NULL
set b.customer_no = a.customer_No 
where b.customer_No is null
```